# Perl - Help Debug

Tags: perl, debugging, while-loop

Would anybody be able to look through my code real fast and try to figure out what I'm not seeing.  I'm having troubles with my Perl debugger at this time, so that's not an option, until I fix it (in the process of investigating).  Here's the code:

```
## Special Variables:
my @args = ();
my $spcl_dir = "$dir_root\\specialprocessing";
my $spcl_log = 'C:\Dad\Eclipse\Repositories\tiffinfo\!specialprocessing.log';

open(FILE, $spcl_log) || die "Couldn't open $spcl_log: $!\n";
for (my $i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
   my $dummy = <FILE>;
}

print "\n$spcl_log\n"; # delete me

while (<FILE>) {
    print "DEBUG START\n";
    my (@fields) = split /;/;
    my $filename = $fields[0];
    print "Processing $filename";
    print "DEBUG END\n";
}

## Copy process
print "\nStarting the copy process over to $spcl_dir:\n";
while (<FILE>) {
    print "DEBUG START!\n";
    my (@fields) = split /;/;
    my $filename = $fields[0];
    print "Copying $filename";
    if (copy("$dir_root\\$filename", "$spcl_dir\\$filename")) {
        print " - Success!\n";
    }
    else { print " - Failure!\n"; }
}
close(FILE);

## Confirmation of file copy
print "Everything look OK?: ";
chomp(my $confirmcopy = <STDIN>);
if ($confirmcopy =~ /^y|^yes/i ) {
    print "\nAttempting to remove original files.\n";
    ## Original file deletion process
    open(FILE, $spcl_log) || die "Couldn't open $spcl_log: $!\n";
    for (my $i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
       my $dummy = <FILE>;
    }

    while (<FILE>) {
        my (@fields) = split /;/;
        my $filename = $fields[0];
        print "Attempting to remove: $filename";
        if (unlink("$dir_root\\$filename")) {
            print " - Success!\n";
        }
        else { print " - Failure!\n"; }
    }
    close(FILE);
}
else { print "Will do, exiting."; exit; }

## Conversion process
print "\nAttempting to convert the files.\n";
open(FILE, $spcl_log) || die "Couldn't open $spcl_log: $!\n";
for (my $i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
   my $dummy = <FILE>;
}

while (<FILE>) {
    my (@fields) = split /;/;
    my $filename = $fields[0];
    print "Starting conversion on $spcl_log\n";
    @args = ("$tiffinfo_path", "$spcl_dir\\$filename", "/bpp=2", "/tifc=4", "/convert=$dir_root\\$filename", "/killmesoftly", "/silent");
    system(@args);
    unlink("$spcl_dir\\$filename");
}
close(FILE);
```

The desired output is the following:

```
Irfanview Found.
Directory exists. Continuing...

Starting the copy process over to c:\dad\tiffs\specialprocessing:
Copying filename2.tif - Failure!
Everything look OK?: n
Will do, exiting.
c:\Dad\Eclipse\Repositories\tiffinfo>perl c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\exectif
finfo.pl
Irfanview Found.
Directory exists. Continuing...

Starting the copy process over to c:\dad\tiffs\specialprocessing:
Copying filename2.tif - Failure!
Everything look OK?: y

Attempting to remove original files.
Attempting to remove: filename2.tif - Failure!

Attempting to convert the files.
Starting conversion on filename2.tif
```

This is obviously going to be different, but you get the picture.  Problem I am having is that everytime I seem to hit the while loop, nothing is processed, non of the code works.  I've even tried simple debugging, such as print statements to see how far the code actually gets, and NOTHING in the while statements execute.

**OUTPUT I RECEIVE (I have to CTRL-C out of the program as it doesn't quit on its own):**

```
C:\Dad\Eclipse\Repositories\tiffinfo\!specialprocessing.log
Starting the copy process over to c:\dad\tiffs\specialprocessing:
Everything look OK?: y
Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)
```

The print statement before the while loop prints the "spcl_log" variable which is:

```
C:\Dad\Eclipse\Repositories\tiffinfo\!specialprocessing.log
```

**CONTENTS OF LOG FILE (first five lines are always going to be skipped - this is what the dummy loop does):**

```
IRFANVIEW BATCH ROUTINE
Work as: Batch Conversion
Output format: TIF
--OPTIONS: CCITT Fax 4  Save gryscl [default ON]
Adv Options: CHANGE COLOR DEPTH 2 colors (B/W) 1 BPP)
filename2.tif;Smpl/Pix & Bits/Smpl are missing.
```

**CONTENTS OF THE WHOLE SCRIPT:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;
use Carp;
use File::Copy;

## Vars
my $dir_root;
my $state;
my $status;
my $batch;
my @files;
my $tifs;
my $executebat;
my $infile;
my $alphachnl;
my $errorlog;
my $corrupt;
my $specialLog;
#my $tiffinfo_path = "c:\\Program Files\\IrfanView\\i_view32.exe";
my $tiffinfo_path = "./converter.pl";

## Usage Vars
my $curVersion = "1.6";
my $options = $ARGV[0];

## Future Use Vars
my $totalErrors = 0;
my $fileCount = 0;

if ($#ARGV >= 0) {
    usage() if $#ARGV > 0;
    usage() if $options eq "-h";
    version() if $options eq "-v";
}

sub version {
    print "CompileTiffInfo.exe\n";
    print "Version: $curVersion\n";
    exit( 0 );
}
sub usage {
    print "\nUsage: compileTiffInfo.exe [OPTIONS]\n";
    print "Processes a directory of TIF images, and outputs the data to 3 different text files.\n\n";
    print "compileTiffInfo.exe (default)\n\tRuns the program through an interactive menu.\n\n";
    print "compileTiffInfo.exe -v\n\tShows version information for this program\n\n";
    print "compileTiffInfo.exe -h\n\tShows this help menu\n";
    exit( 0 );
}

system 'cls';
## Check if tiffinfo is installed.
if (-e $tiffinfo_path) {
    print "Irfanview Found." . "\n";
}
else {
    print "Irfanview was not found." . "\n";
    exit ( 0 );
}

## Check passcode
if (defined($ARGV[0])) {
    if ($ARGV[0] ne $curVersion ) {
        print "Passcode not recognized.";
        exit ( 0 );
    }
}
else { 
    print "Passcode not recognized.";
    exit ( 0 ); 
}

## Start of actual program; asks user where the TIF images are located.
print "Where are your TIF file(s) located? (C:\\directory\\of\\your\\tiff\\files): ";
chomp($dir_root = <STDIN>);
if (! -d $dir_root) {
    print "Directory doesn't exist!\n";
    exit;
}
if ($dir_root =~ tr/ / /) {
    print "There's spaces in your path. Try again.\n";
    exit;
}
if ($dir_root =~ /\\$/) {
    print "You ended with a slash. This is not allowed; try again.";
    exit;
}
print "State: [LA,NM,OK,UT,TX,WY] - [--,none,other]: ";
chomp($state = uc(<STDIN>));
if ($state eq "") {
    print "Whoa! No data was entered.  Exiting.";
    exit;
}
if ($state eq "OTHER" || $state eq "NONE" || $state eq "--") {
    print "\n ** NOTE: Entering into STANDARD SPREADSHEET OUTPUT MODE **\n\n"
}
print "Status [nr][hs][tye] or Anything Descriptive: ";
chomp($status = lc(<STDIN>));
print "Batch #? ";
chomp($batch = uc(<STDIN>));

## Define the output file, based on user input
my $batOutput = "\!".$state.$status."INFOraw.txt";

open (BATFILE, "> \!".$state.$status."INFOraw.bat");
print BATFILE "\@echo off\n";
close (BATFILE);

open (BATFILE, ">> \!".$state.$status."INFOraw.bat");
print BATFILE "type nul > $batOutput\n";
close (BATFILE);

## Get a list of tif files from dir_root
## No trailing slash is allowed
opendir(DIR, $dir_root);
@files = grep(/\.ti[f]{1,2}$/i,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

## Check to see if array has data
if (@files) {
    foreach $tifs (@files) {
        open (BATFILE, ">> \!".$state.$status."INFOraw.bat");
        print BATFILE "tiffinfo TYPE $dir_root"."\\".$tifs." \>> ".$batOutput."\n";
        ## Need to write to INFO file, for each file, eliminating the .bat file.
        close (BATFILE);
    }
}
## if array is null (no data), then no tif files were found
else {
    print "No Tiff files were found.";
    exit;
}

## Run bat script
print "Attempting to execute .bat script now...\n";
$executebat = system 'call !'.$state.$status.'INFOraw.bat > NUL 2>&1';
if ( $executebat != 0 ) { 
        die "Failed executing .bat script. \n"; 
}
else { print "Ran .bat script successfully.\n\n"; }

## Debugging Only
#$infile = 'data.txt';
$infile = $batOutput;

## Output File Handles (open)
open(OUT1,"> \!".$state.$status."INFO.txt") or die "Can't open \!".$state.$status."INFO.txt: $!"; 
open(OUT2,"> \!".$state.$status."INFOspdsht.txt") or die "Can't open \!".$state.$status."INFO.txt $!";
open(ERRLOG,"> \!errors.log") or die "Can't open !errors.log $!";
open(CORRUPT,"> \!corrupt.log") or die "Can't open !corrupt.log $!";
open(SPECIAL,"> \!specialprocessing.log") or die "Can't open !specialprocessing.log $!";

## Print Headers To spdsht file
print OUT2 ";;;;Whitespace;;DPI ReSize;;;\n";
print OUT2 "Filename;Comp;AlphCnl;Foto;Wid;Len;Res 0;x0;;;MB\n";
print CORRUPT "Filename;Reason For Failure\n";
print SPECIAL "IRFANVIEW BATCH ROUTINE\nWork as: Batch Conversion\nOutput format: TIF\n--OPTIONS: CCITT Fax 4  Save gryscl [default ON]\nAdv Options: CHANGE COLOR DEPTH 2 colors (B/W) 1 BPP)\n";

## Configuration Data for masking data output
my %config = (
    'LZW'                               => 'colors',
    'Lempel-Ziv & Welch encoding'       => 'colors',
    'CCITT Group 4'                     => 'bkwhts',
    'CCITT Group 4 facsimile encoding'  => 'bkwhts',
    'None'                              => 'none',
    'none'                              => 'none',
    'RGB color'                         => 'colors',
    'min-is-white'                      => 'bkwhts',
    'min-is-black'                      => 'bkwhts',
    'palette color (RGB from colormap)' => 'colors',
    'Resolution'                        => sub {
                                            my @r = split(/, /, shift);
                                            $r[0] =~ s/\D//g;
                                            $r[1] =~ s/\D//g;
                                            return @r[0,1];
    },
);

my @config = keys %config;

#my $file = $infile; # set this as needed.
my $file = "data.txt";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "can't open <$file> for reading $!";

$/ = "TYPE:\n";
while ( my $record = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $record;
    next if $record eq '';
    $record =~ s/(TIFF Directory at offset .+)\n//;

    ## Future use, for incrementing errors
    my $errorCount = 0;

    my ($fullpath, $data) = split(/\n/, $record, 2);
    $fullpath =~ s/:$//;

    my ($drv, $path, $file) = File::Spec->splitpath($fullpath);

    ## Start processing the file
    print "Processing $file\n";
    $fileCount++;

    ## Get Compression Scheme data
    my $cs = $config{$1} if ($data =~ s/\s{2}Compression Scheme:\s+(.*?)\n//);
    if (!defined $cs) {
        print "[ERROR]: Compression Scheme for $file not found.\n";
        #print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Compression Scheme for $file not found.\n";
        $cs = "unknwn";
        $errorCount++;
    }   

    ## Get Photometric Interpretation data
    my $pi = $config{$1} if ($data =~ s/\s{2}Photometric Interpretation:\s+(.*?)\n//);
    if (!defined $pi) {
        print "[ERROR]: Photometric Interpretation for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Photometric Interpretation for $file not found.\n";
        $pi = "unknwn";
        $errorCount++;
    }

    ## Get Bits/Sample data
    my $bits = $1 if ($data =~ s/\s{2}Bits\/Sample:\s+(.*?)\n//);
    if (!defined $bits) {
        print "[ERROR]: Bits/Sample data for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Bits/Sample data for $file not found.\n";
        $bits = "unknwn";
        $errorCount++;
    }

    ## Get Samples/Pixel data
    my $pixels = $1 if ($data =~ s/\s{2}Samples\/Pixel:\s+(.*?)\n//);
    if (!defined $pixels) {
        print "[ERROR]: Samples/Pixel data for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Samples/Pixel data for $file not found.\n";
        $pixels = "unknwn";
        $errorCount++;
    }

    ## Get AlphaChnl Value (bits * pixels)
    if (!($pixels eq '') && !($bits eq '')) {
        if (!($pixels eq "unknwn") && !($bits eq "unknwn")) {
            $alphachnl = $bits * $pixels;
            if ($alphachnl == 1) {
                $alphachnl = "bkwhts";
            }   
            elsif ($alphachnl == 8) {
                $alphachnl = "colors";
            }
            elsif ($alphachnl == 24) {
                $alphachnl = "doLOGO";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $alphachnl = "unknwn";
        print "[ERROR]: Alpha Channel for $file had issues (probably due to Bits/Sample or Sample/Pixel issue.)\n";
        $errorCount++;
        print "[ERROR]: Alpha Channel for $file had issues (probably due to Bits/Sample or Sample/Pixel issue.)\n";
    }

    ## Get Resolution data
    my @r = $config{'Resolution'}->($1) if ($data =~ s/\s{2}Resolution:\s+(.*?)\n//);

    ## Get Width/Length data
    my ($w, $l) = ($1, $2) if ($data =~ s/\s{2}Image Width: (\d+) Image Length: (\d+)\n//);

    ## Width
    if (!defined $w) {
        print "[ERROR]: Width for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Width for $file not found.\n";
        $errorCount++;
        #next;
    }

    ## Length
    if (!defined $l) {
        print "[ERROR]: Length for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Length for $file not found.\n";
        $errorCount++;
        #next;
    }

    ## Width
    if (!defined $w) {
        print "[ERROR]: Width for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Width for $file not found.\n";
        $errorCount++;
    }

    ## Length
    if (!defined $l) {
        print "[ERROR]: Length for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Length for $file not found.\n";
        $errorCount++;
        $l = "unknwn";
    }

    ## Resolution
    if (!defined $r[0] || !defined $r[1]) {
        print "[ERROR]: Resolution for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Resolution for $file not found.\n";
        $errorCount++;
        #next;
    }   

    ## Resolution
    if (!defined $r[0] || !defined $r[1]) {
        print "[ERROR]: Resolution for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Resolution for $file not found.\n";
        $errorCount++;
        $r[0] = "unknwn";
        $r[1] = "unknwn";
    }   
    ## Get Rows/Strip data
    my $strip = $1 if ($data =~ s/\s{2}Rows\/Strip:\s+(.*?)\n//);
    if (!defined $strip) {
        print "[ERROR]: Rows/Strip data for $file not found.\n";
        print ERRLOG "[ERROR]: Rows/Strip data for $file not found.\n";
        $errorCount++;
    }

    ## Get Size of TIF(F) file(s)
    #my $filesize = (-s $fullpath) / (1024 * 1024); ## Uncomment when in production
    my $filesize = "2"; ## REMOVE - Testing Purposes only to "fake" an image size.
    my $size_in_mb = sprintf "%.2f", $filesize;


    ## Error Check
    if ($errorCount == 8) {
        print "[FAILURE]: Not processed, image may be CORRUPT.\n";
        print CORRUPT "$file;High Probability - IMAGE CORRUPT.";
        $totalErrors++;
        next;
    }
    if ($pixels eq "unknwn" && $bits eq "unknwn") {
        print "[INFO]: Specially processed image.\n";
        print SPECIAL "$file;Smpl/Pix & Bits/Smpl are missing.\n";
        $totalErrors++;
        next;
    }
    if ($errorCount > 0) {
        print "[ERROR]: $file was not processed, too many errors.\n";
        $totalErrors++;
        next;
    }

    $data =~ s/\n$//;

    ## ** For Debugging - Prints To Screen **
    ## print $/, join(':', $file, $cs, $bits, $pi, $w, $l, @r, $size_in_mb, "\n"), $data, "\n";

    print OUT1 $/, join(';', $file, $cs, $bits, $pixels, $pi, $w, $l, @r, $size_in_mb, "\n"), $data, "\n";

    ## LA Output
    if ($state eq "LA") {
        print OUT2 "$file;", "$cs;", "$alphachnl;", "$pi;", "$w;", "$l;", "$r[0];$r[1];;;", "$size_in_mb;;","\'$batch;;;;","start;","$file;;;;;;;;;;","$size_in_mb;","move;","$file;","$dir_root\\done;", "\n"; 
    }
    ## NM Output
    elsif ($state eq "NM") {
        print OUT2 "$file;", "$cs;", "$alphachnl;", "$pi;", "$w;", "$l;", "$r[0];$r[1];;;", "$size_in_mb;;","\'$batch;;;;","start;","$file;","$size_in_mb;","move;","$file;","$dir_root\\done;", "\n";
        next;
        next;
    }
    ## OK/UT Output
    elsif ($state eq "OK" || $state eq "UT") {
        print OUT2 "$file;", "$cs;", "$alphachnl;", "$pi;", "$w;", "$l;", "$r[0];$r[1];;;", "$size_in_mb;;","\'$batch;;;;","start;","$file;","$size_in_mb;","move;","$file;","$dir_root\\done;","start;",$file."f;","move;",$file."f;","$dir_root\\done\\TEMPdone;", "\n";
        next;
        next;
    }
    ## TX/WY Output
    elsif ($state eq "TX" || $state eq "WY") {
        print OUT2 "$file;", "$cs;", "$alphachnl;", "$pi;", "$w;", "$l;", "$r[0];$r[1];", "move $dir_root\\$file $dir_root\\$cs\\$file;;", "$size_in_mb;;", "\'$batch;;;","start;", "$dir_root\\$cs\\$file;", "$file;","$size_in_mb;","move;", "$dir_root\\$cs\\$file;", "$dir_root\\done;","start;", $file."f;", "move;", $file."f;", "$dir_root\\done\\TEMPdone;", "\n";
        next;
        next;
    }
    elsif ($state eq "NONE" || $state eq "--" || $state eq "OTHER") {
        print OUT2 "$file;", "$cs;", "$alphachnl;", "$pi;", "$w;", "$l;", "$r[0];$r[1];", "$size_in_mb\n";
        next;
        next;
    }
}

print "\nTotal Files Processed: $fileCount\n";
print "High Probability Failures: $totalErrors  /  Failure Rate: ".$totalErrors * 100 / $fileCount."%\n";

close (OUT1) or die "Can't close out1: $!"; 
close (OUT2) or die "Can't close out2: $!"; 
close (ERRLOG) or die "Can't close error log: $!";
close (CORRUPT) or die "Can't close corrupt log: $!";
close (SPECIAL) or die "Can't close corrupt log: $!";
close ($fh) or die "Can't close $fh: $!";

$errorlog = "\!errors.log";
if (-s $errorlog == 0) {
    unlink($errorlog) or die "Can't delete $errorlog : $!"; 
}
else { print "Error log saved.\n\n"; }

#$corrupt = "\!corrupt.log";
#if (-s $corrupt == 0) {
#   unlink($corrupt) or die "Can't delete $corrupt : $!";
#}
#else { print "Corrupt log saved."; }

#$specialLog = "\!specialprocessing.log";
#if (-s $specialLog == 0) {
#   unlink($specialLog) or die "Can't delete $specialLog : $!";
#}
#else { print "Special Processing log saved."; }

## Starting Tiffinfo Processing:

my $spcl_dir = "dst";
my $spcl_log = "!specialprocessing.log";

print "DIR_ROOT: $dir_root\n";
print "SPCL_LOG: $spcl_log\n";
print "TIFFINFO_PATH: $tiffinfo_path\n";

sub get_files_list
{
    my($log) = @_;
    open my $file, '<', $log or croak "Couldn't open $log: $!\n";
    # Skip heading lines
    for (my $i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++)
    {
        my $dummy = <$file>;
    }
    my @files;
    while (<$file>)
    {
        my (@fields) = split /;/;
        my $filename = $fields[0];
        push @files, $filename;
    }
    close $file or croak "Couldn't close $log: $!\n";
    return @files;
}

my @spcl_files = get_files_list($spcl_log);
print "\n$spcl_log\n"; # delete me

## Copy original files
print "\nStarting the copy process over to $spcl_dir:\n";
foreach my $filename (@spcl_files)
{
    print "Copying $filename";
    if (copy("$dir_root/$filename", "$spcl_dir/$filename"))
    {
            print " - Success!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print " - Failure! ($!)\n";
    }
}

## Confirmation of file copy
print "Everything look OK?: ";
chomp(my $confirmcopy = <STDIN>);
if ($confirmcopy !~ /^y|^yes/i )
{
    print "Will do, exiting.\n";
    exit 0;
}

## Delete original files
print "\nAttempting to remove original files.\n";
foreach my $filename (@spcl_files)
{
    print "Attempting to remove: $filename";
    if (unlink("$dir_root/$filename"))
    {
        print " - Success!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print " - Failure! ($!)\n";
    }
}

## Conversion process
print "\nAttempting to convert the files.\n";

foreach my $filename (@spcl_files)
{
    print "Starting conversion on $filename\n";
    my @args = ("$tiffinfo_path", "$spcl_dir/$filename", "/bpp=2",
                "/tifc=4", "/convert=$dir_root/$filename",
                "/killmesoftly", "/silent");
    if (system(@args) != 0)
    {
        carp "Failed to convert $filename ($!)";
    }
    else
    {
        unlink("$spcl_dir/$filename") or carp "Failed to unlink $spcl_dir/$filename ($!)";
    }
}
```

**NOTES:**
Only thing I changed was I added:

```
print "DIR_ROOT: $dir_root\n";
print "SPCL_LOG: $spcl_log\n";
print "TIFFINFO_PATH: $tiffinfo_path\n";
```

...for debugging purposes. And the other other thing is that I renamed the array `@files` to `@spcl_files` since `@files` was already defined in my main script.

**STILL THE PROBLEM**:
Here's my current output:

```
Irfanview Found.
Where are your TIF file(s) located? (C:\directory\of\your\tiff\files): c:\dad\ti
ffs
State: [LA,NM,OK,UT,TX,WY] - [--,none,other]: tx
Status [nr][hs][tye] or Anything Descriptive: nr
Batch #? 1
Attempting to execute .bat script now...
Ran .bat script successfully.

Processing filename.tif
Processing filename2.tif
[ERROR]: Bits/Sample data for filename2.tif not found.
[ERROR]: Samples/Pixel data for filename2.tif not found.
[INFO]: Specially processed image.

Total Files Processed: 2
High Probability Failures: 1  /  Failure Rate: 50%
Error log saved.

DIR_ROOT: c:\dad\tiffs
SPCL_LOG: !specialprocessing.log
TIFFINFO_PATH: ./converter.pl

!specialprocessing.log

Starting the copy process over to dst:
Everything look OK?: n
```

For staters, it still doesn't show the filename after the "Starting the copy process over to dst" and whether I hit Y or N for the "Everything look OK?" part, it just hangs there and does nothing.

**NEW CODE/OUTPUT 11/26 @ 3PM CST:**

```
my @spcl_files = get_files_list($spcl_log);
print $spcl_files[0];
print "YO";
```

Output:

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at compileTiffInfo.pl line 445.
YO
Starting the copy process over to dst:
Everything look OK?: Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)
```

Thanks in advanced! :)

Comment: Share the output you actually see.  You have a print statement before the first while loop.  What does it print?

Comment: What is the content of the log file? Can you post an example? What is the dummy loop at top where you read 5 lines from the log file? Alos you did not post the whole code.

Comment: Does the file you open actually contain more than 5 lines?

Comment: Can you post what you're getting as output right now?

Comment: Just updated my main question - has all updated information requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up input separator (on line 190):

```
$/ = "TYPE:\n";
```

Comment: Yes...?  Please explain a bit.

Comment: Search for "input record separator" or just search for `$/` on the perlvar manpage http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html.

Comment: Wow! This actually fixed it! :D.  Placed original file handle (line 185) into curly braces, and changed the input record separator to `local $/ = "TYPE:\n";` and all the code magically starting working like it was suppose to.  jira, good eye!

Comment: @drewrockshard: I wrote "Maybe you changed the input record separator ($/) somewhere?" two days ago. Exactly what I suspected...

Answer (score 2):

Your DEBUG START, DEBUG END `while` loop is eating all the data in the file - and then you expect the main loop to read new data from the same file.

Either:

- Lose the debug loop.

Or:

- Revise the debug loop to generate the list of files in an array, and then have the main loop read the file names from the array instead of the input file.

Your desired output isn't all available from the code shown, either - the first line, in particular, does not seem to have any code to print it.

---

#### Deconstruction of code

You code has the same bit of code written out 3 times - the stuff that skips 5 lines and splits out the file name.  In the answer to [SO 4272615](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272615/), you were given a set functions that would give you an array with the list of file names to process.  Use functions - they make code easier to manage!

I observe that your code does  not include '`use strict;`' or '`use warnings`'; experts use them all the time to make sure they don't make mistakes, and beginners need to use them all the time to make sure they don't make mistakes.  As it happens, the only issues it throws up are 'undeclared variables', so your code is not bad.

When I run the code (hacked so the directories are appropriate for my machine), the first DEBUG loop runs and eats up the data; the second loop therefore reports nothing.  If I try to let it run, it then complains that the function `main::copy` is not found.  Presumably, that is fixed by adding '`use File::Copy;`', but it helps if you post the actual code you are using, not a butchered semblance to it.

Even on Windows, you are better off not using '`\\`' in the pathnames; you can use '`/`' in them and the o/s is quite happy; it is `cmd.exe` that is not keen on slashes instead of backslashes.

#### Simulation environment

The code below WFM - works for me (test environment: MacOS X 10.6.5, Perl 5.13.4).  I created a file 'data.file' from the previous question.  I created sub-directories 'safe', 'src' and 'dst', and created empty files 'filename2.tif', 'filename4.tif', 'filename6.tif', 'filename8.tif' in 'safe'.  I then linked the files from 'safe' to 'src' so I could rerun the script easily, despite it unlinking the input files.

```
ln safe/* src
```

I also created a script 'converter':

```
echo "$0 $@"
```

#### Example Output

The output from the program was then:

```
data.file

Starting the copy process over to dst:
Copying filename2.tif - Success!
Copying filename4.tif - Success!
Copying filename6.tif - Success!
Copying filename8.tif - Success!
Everything look OK?: y

Attempting to remove original files.
Attempting to remove: filename2.tif - Success!
Attempting to remove: filename4.tif - Success!
Attempting to remove: filename6.tif - Success!
Attempting to remove: filename8.tif - Success!

Attempting to convert the files.
Starting conversion on filename2.tif
./converter dst/filename2.tif /bpp=2 /tifc=4 /convert=src/filename2.tif /killmesoftly /silent
Starting conversion on filename4.tif
./converter dst/filename4.tif /bpp=2 /tifc=4 /convert=src/filename4.tif /killmesoftly /silent
Starting conversion on filename6.tif
./converter dst/filename6.tif /bpp=2 /tifc=4 /convert=src/filename6.tif /killmesoftly /silent
Starting conversion on filename8.tif
./converter dst/filename8.tif /bpp=2 /tifc=4 /convert=src/filename8.tif /killmesoftly /silent
```

#### Reconstruction of code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use File::Copy;

my $spcl_dir = "dst";
my $spcl_log = "data.file";
my $dir_root = "src";
my $tiffinfo_path = "./converter";

sub get_files_list
{
    my($log) = @_;
    open my $file, '<', $log or croak "Couldn't open $log: $!\n";
    # Skip heading lines
    for (my $i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++)
    {
        my $dummy = <$file>;
    }
    my @files;
    while (<$file>)
    {
        my (@fields) = split /;/;
        my $filename = $fields[0];
        push @files, $filename;
    }
    close $file or croak "Couldn't close $log: $!\n";
    return @files;
}

my @files = get_files_list($spcl_log);
print "\n$spcl_log\n"; # delete me

## Copy original files
print "\nStarting the copy process over to $spcl_dir:\n";
foreach my $filename (@files)
{
    print "Copying $filename";
    if (copy("$dir_root/$filename", "$spcl_dir/$filename"))
    {
            print " - Success!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print " - Failure! ($!)\n";
    }
}

## Confirmation of file copy
print "Everything look OK?: ";
chomp(my $confirmcopy = <STDIN>);
if ($confirmcopy !~ /^y|^yes/i )
{
    print "Will do, exiting.\n";
    exit 0;
}

## Delete original files
print "\nAttempting to remove original files.\n";
foreach my $filename (@files)
{
    print "Attempting to remove: $filename";
    if (unlink("$dir_root/$filename"))
    {
        print " - Success!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print " - Failure! ($!)\n";
    }
}

## Conversion process
print "\nAttempting to convert the files.\n";

foreach my $filename (@files)
{
    print "Starting conversion on $filename\n";
    my @args = ("$tiffinfo_path", "$spcl_dir/$filename", "/bpp=2",
                "/tifc=4", "/convert=$dir_root/$filename",
                "/killmesoftly", "/silent");
    if (system(@args) != 0)
    {
        carp "Failed to convert $filename ($!)";
    }
    else
    {
        unlink("$spcl_dir/$filename") or carp "Failed to unlink $spcl_dir/$filename ($!)";
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- Check that the conversion succeeds (`system`) before removing the file.
- Check that the `unlink` succeeds.
- Include the Perl error information '`$!`' in the error messages.
- Use '`use Carp;`' and `carp` and `croak` instead of `warn` and `die`.
- Function `get_file_list()` used to get the list of files - just once.
- The function uses a lexical file handle `$file` instead of `FILE`.
- It also uses the three argument form of `open`, which is the most reliable form.
- It also uses the low priority 'or' connective instead of '||'.  (In context, with the parentheses around the `open`, the '||' is correct; if you omit the parentheses as in the rewrite, then 'or' is necessary.)
- The code does an early exit when the response is 'do not continue'.
- The `foreach` loops iterate of the list of files.
- The `exit` has an explicit status of 0 (success).

Comment: The debug loop does not run either, so that is not the primary problem.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Jonathan.  I've updated the main question with my current output and ALL my code, not just the snippets.  It seems to hang in the same place, and with your original code I tested and it worked OUTSIDE my program - same with my original code that I posted; my code worked, but once I dropped it into my program, it started hanging in the same places.  Maybe I'm missing something somewhere that I just don't see.  I'm using Eclipse w/ EPIC, and there are no warnings/errors in my source, according to Eclipse/EPIC.

Comment: @drewrockshard: I've taken a look at the revised code you pasted up top...and don't see what the problem is.  I neutralized all the batch-file code and the code related to the config and so on (there are minor issues, like the resolution block is repeated).  With that all disabled, I then see essentially the output I posted.  So, you are going to need to identify which steps in your code are hanging, either using the built-in Perl debugger or by adding trace print statements.

Comment: I still can't figure out why it's doing this.  None of the code that you created even references the new code, so I'm not sure why the "main" code that runs the program would be causing the issue.  It's like I drop in the new code, and now the new code stops working correctly.  The only place it hangs is on the "questioning" and it doesn't output any information.  See my new output (in main question), when I add `print $spcl_files[0];` after the get_files_list($spcl_log); declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are obviously not getting anything back from `<FILE>`. 
Maybe you changed the input record seperator (`$/`) somewhere?

To investigate, extend the for loop to:

```
for (my $i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
    my $dummy = <FILE>;
    print $dummy;
}
```

That should give you a pretty good idea what is going on here.

Also, consider reading the file in an array (`my @lines = <FILE>;`), since you use the information more than once.

Comment: Adding `print $dummy;` do the code, gives the following error: `Use of uninitialized value in print at compileTiffInfo.pl`.  The error happens on the line that I added the print statement.

Comment: Ok, so there is a problem with the file. a) use the three-operand version of open: `open(FILE, '<', $spcl_log)` to make sure you are actually reading. b) Rename/copy the file to some other place and change to path to make sure there are no permission/path issues. c) double-check that there is actually something in the file.