# perl read file from specified line thru the end

Tags: perl

I'm new with perl. I'm trying to read a large comma separate file, split and grab only some columns. I could create it with some internet help, but I'm struggling to change to code to start reading from a specific line thru the end of the file.
my need is open file start reading on line 12, split ',' grab column 0,2,10,11 and concatenate those needed columns with '\t'.

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $filename = 'file_to_read.csv';
open(FILER, $filename) or die "Could not read $filename.";
open(FILEW, ">$filename.txt")     || die "couldn't create the file\n";
while(<FILER>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split(',', $_);
  print FILEW "$fields[0]\t$fields[3]\t$fields[10]\t$fields[11]\n";
}
close FILER;
close FILEW;
```

here is the file example:

```
[Header]
GSGT Version: X
Processing Date:12/01/2010 7:20 PM
Content:
Num SNPs:
Total SNPs:
Num Samples:
Total Samples:
Sample:
[Data]

SNP Name,Chromosome,Pos,GC Score,Theta,R,X,Y,X Raw,Y Raw,B Allele Freq,Log R Ratio,Allele1 - TOP,Allele2 - TOP
1:10001102-G-T,1,10001102,0.4159,0.007,0.477,0.472,0.005,6281,126,0.0000,-0.2581,A,A
1:100011159-T-G,1,100011159,0.4259,0.972,0.859,0.036,0.822,807,3648,0.9942,-0.0304,C,C
1:10002775-GA,1,10002775,0.4234,0.977,1.271,0.043,1.228,809,5140,0.9892,0.0111,G,G
```

Comment: Check the value of `$.`. Don't do anything until it's at least 12.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl - Start reading from specific line, and only get first column of it line, until end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272484/perl-start-reading-from-specific-line-and-only-get-first-column-of-it-line-u)

Comment: What [Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/82262/matt-jacob) means is just add the line `next if $. < 12;` before `chomp` and you're good.  See [`$.` in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than skipping until a specific line number, which may vary from file to file, it is best to keep track of the current section of the file marked by `[Header]`, `[Data]` etc.

This solution keeps a state variable `$section` which is updated to the current section name every time a `[Section]` label is encountered in the file. Everything from the `Data` section is summarised and printed

A similar thing could be done with the column headers, using names instead of numbers to select the fields to be output, but I have chosen to keep the complexity down instead

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $filename = 'file_to_read.csv';

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};

my $section = "";

while ( <$fh> ) {

    next unless /\S/;            # Skip empty lines

    if ( $section eq 'Data' ) {  # Skip unless we're in the [Data] section
        chomp;
        my @fields = split /,/;
        say join ',', @fields[0,3,10,11];
    }
    elsif ( /\[(\w+)\]/ ) {
        $section = $1;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
SNP Name,GC Score,B Allele Freq,Log R Ratio
1:10001102-G-T,0.4159,0.0000,-0.2581
1:100011159-T-G,0.4259,0.9942,-0.0304
1:10002775-GA,0.4234,0.9892,0.0111
```

Answer (score -1):

please assign a variable to count the lines processed like `my $line_count = 0;`

and inside the beginning of while loop increment the varialbe `$line_count++;`

and skip if the line count is below 12 ie , `next if $line_count > 12;`